# PHP append duplicate value

Tags: php, duplicates, append, stock-data

I'm trying to append data in file 
I have an array result contains this value :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Fanny [asset] => 1034 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Gabriel [asset] => 1089 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Martin [asset_no] => 1520> ) )
```

I use a foreach to get the values and then insert them in a file :

```
foreach ($result as $value){
  $name = $value['name'];
  $asset = $value['asset'];
  $dir = "C:/Users/<users>/data";
  if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir,0777);
  }
file_put_contents("$dir/data", "$name , $data \r", FILE_APPEND);
```

The data in my data file is :

```
Fanny, 1034
Gabriel, 1089
Martin, 1520
```

When I rerun my file it duplicates the values in the file that stores my data:

```
Fanny, 1034
Gabriel, 1089
Martin, 1520
Fanny, 1034
Gabriel, 1089
Martin, 1520
```

I would like to prevent duplication for existing values 
Can anyone tell me where the error. Thank you for your help !

Comment: You are blindly appending new content to the existing one every time, so how could you expect any other result? You will need to read your existing data from the file first, and then check if there is value in there you need to overwrite, instead of appending to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove FILE_APPEND parameter as it appends data to the end of the file , as you are re-inserting all data again and again you don't need old data so you can remove it thus file_put_contents will remove old file data and store the new data instead

if you need to compare old data stored in the file and new data in array I would suggest you read data from file first , convert it to array ( with json_decode maybe ) and create a function to loop through 2 arrays and append values that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my problems i have use one array with data and compare my data i want to add that i wanted to insert :

```
$file = file_get_contents("$dir/data");
$data = explode("\r",$file);
foreach ($result as $value) {
  $name = $value['name'];
  $asset = $value['asset'];
  $message = "$name, $asset";
  if (in_array($message, $data)){
     echo "$message already exist ";
  } else {
     file_put_contents("$dir/data", "$message\r", FILE_APPEND);
  }
}
```